# Updated setState Array from fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like this is a dumb question but I can't find the answer.
Currently I have state:

```
this.state = {
      jsonReturnedValue: []
}
```

I do a fetch request and get an array of data:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/printing/postcards-printing')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
      this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue, json.printCategory.products] }, () => console.log(this.state));
      });
  }
```

This pushes the array pulled from my fetch request but it creates this:

```
jsonReturnedValue
   [0]Array
      [3] Array <--- the array I'm wanting is nested in the original array.
```

What I need is

```
jsonReturnedValue
   [3]Array
```

I need my fetch response not to be nested in the already made array.

Comment: Can we see the response structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spread both of the arrays you want to concatenate:

```
this.setState({
    jsonReturnedValue: [
        ...this.state.jsonReturnedValue,
        ...json.printCategory.products,
    ],
}, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Or use `Array#concat`:

```
this.setState({
    jsonReturnedValue: this.state.jsonReturnedValue
        .concat(json.printCategory.products),
}, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Or if you wanted to replace rather than concatenate:

```
this.setState({
    jsonReturnedValue: json.printCategory.products,
}, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're so close:

```
this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue, ...json.printCategory.products] }
```

You want to concatenate those arrays, but what you were doing (with out the second spread operator) was just adding an array as the item item of another.

Answer (score 1):

I see it being one of two issues.

Option 1: `[...this.state.jsonReturnedValue, ...json.printCategory.products]` Note the spread operator on the second index. I think it's this one!

Option 2: We should see the response body structure but it may be that you need to select a lower-level property on the response. For example, `json.data.printCategory.products` instead of `json.printCategory.products`.